# C# force windows service to use proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, windows-services, httpwebrequest

Using Proxy Switcher with a private proxy (login & password authentication). In debug mode my win service works fine: it runs identically to console app under current logged on user with proxy set for browser. This code do the job just fine (may be, even a bit excessive):

```
// use default proxy settings (like those in browser)
HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
// create web request object for URL
HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
// set default proxy credentials for object
webreq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

But... it stops working when running compiled release of win service under Local System, i.e. it queries URL via direct internet connection without proxy. How to make win service to use proxy, which is set for IE by Proxy Switcher or even hardcoded in c# (that will do too)?

Comment: I just came accross this piece of doc from MS that might be of help in your case : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN#http-proxy

Answer (score 0):

Made hardcoded proxy, it works without Proxy Switcher:

```
// use hardcoded proxy (works for win service under local system account)
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("000.000.000.00", 50100); // ip & port
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password"); 
webreq.Proxy = proxy;
```

Still interested in more flexible variant with proxy inherited by win service automatically - that initially set by Proxy Switcher and used in web browser. Pls. advise

Comment: I consider current proxy setting for user/users can be obtained from windows registry, but access to corresponding properties through system's object model (or something) - would be more convenient and preferrable